# Foreach não traz os campos marcados

Tags: php, jquery

Colegas.

Tenho o formulário abaixo onde coloco o tamanho, estoque e se o produto é por encomenda. Se for por encomenda, basta selecionar o produto conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tamanho e o estoque consigo pegar normalmente os valores, porém o campo Encomenda só me traz o primeiro valor. Veja o código:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Encomenda[]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda</label>
```

JQuery que adiciona mais campos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

Estou pegando da seguinte forma:

```
$tamanho = $_POST["Tamanho"];
$estoque = $_POST["Estoque"];
$encomenda = $_POST["Encomenda"];

$metodos->cadastrar($tamanho,$estoque,$encomenda);
```

A classe do métodos:

```
public function cadastrar($tamanho,$estoque,$encomenda){
.....   
 for($i = 0; $i <= count($tamanho); $i++){
     if($estoque[$i] != ""){
        mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO tabela VALUES(null,'".$tamanho[$i]."','".$estoque[$i]."','".$encomenda[$i]."');");
     }
  }   
.....
}
```

POST ATUALIZADO

Alterei a seguinte linha:

```
novoCampo.find("[type=checkbox]").val("Sim");
```

Consegui pegar os valores, porém ao jogar no banco de dados, conforme a imagem acima, ele me retorna da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o IDEstoques 6 tinha que receber o valor **Sim** e não o IDEstoques 5

Comment: Faça um `var_dump` da variável `$_POST` para vermos exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Olá Kadu. Constatei que o problema realmente está no Jquery e não no PHP, pois quando criei o campo checkbox manualmente, consegui pegar os dados, mas quando coloco de volta conforme no post, só passa o primeiro valor.

Comment: Teste alterando a linha `novoCampo.find("input").val("");` para `novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");` e depois dela adiciona a seguinte `novoCampo.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('selected', false);`, Verifica se o problema persiste.. Você envia os dados via ajax? Se for, poste o código do ajax também...

Comment: Olá KaduAmaral. Fiz conforme solicitou, consegui pegar os valores, mas diferente do que ocorreu na alteração do meu post, ele cadastra agora nos dois primeiros campos, mesmo deixando marcado conforme a imagem do meu post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está limpando o valor do *checkbox* com a linha

```
novoCampo.find("input").val("");
```

Quando for *checkbox* você deve alterar seu estado via `prop` e não o seu valor `val`. Faça o seguinte:

```
novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val(""); 
novoCampo.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Olá Kadu. Certo. Fiz conforme você falou, consegui pegar os valores, mas no banco de dados ele cadastra sequencialmente e não conforme selecionado na imagem.

Comment: @Fox.11 ai já entramos na questão da lógica. Por exemplo, campos do tipo `checkbox` quando não são marcados, eles não são enviados para o post. Então você tem que verificar a lógica do seu `if($estoque[$i] != "")`. Sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta caso não consiga resolver isto.

Comment: Ah sim, não envio via ajax.

Comment: Combinado. Sua resposta me ajudou a pegar os valores e foi a solução para meu problema aqui no post. Obrigado.